# How to get items which together satisfy quantity requirement? (WHILE Loop OR CTE?) postresql

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get the id's of delivery note items which satisfy the quantity requirement. The items have to be ordered by a specific order like FIFO LIFO

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE delivery_note_item (id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY, stock_item_id BIGINT, quantity BIGINT, received TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO delivery_note_item (id, stock_item_id, quantity, received) 
VALUES 
(1, 1, 5, '2023-08-01 00:00:00'),
(2, 1, 3, '2023-08-02 00:00:00'),
(3, 1, 9, '2023-08-03 00:00:00'), 
(4, 1, 8, '2023-08-04 00:00:00');
```

So, if I need 10 stock_item (id = 1) by FIFO (order by received ASC), then the query should return 1, 2, 3.
if I need 10 stock_items by HIFO, then the output should be 4, 3.

Is anybody can help me to find a solution for this problem?

I am not sure, that it would be better to use WHILE loop or a CTE or REQURSIVE CTE?
Thanks

Comment: in reality order by id and order by timestamp is not equal, becuse received can be filled later.
Also, the dataset is quite big, so if possible, I would prefer to get back only those which I need.

Comment: Ordering is fine. The real question is how to define WHERE. WHERE sum(quantity) > 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve x rows based on quantity, use the `sum()` window function to calculate the running total and then subtract the quantity:

```
select *
from (
  select *, sum(quantity) over (partition by stock_item_id order by received) - quantity as FIFO_running,
            sum(quantity) over (partition by stock_item_id order by received DESC) - quantity as LIFO_running
  from delivery_note_item
) as s
where stock_item_id = 1 and fifo_running <= 10
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/56gkEBOR)

Comment: Looks great – just that I wouldn't calculate the unused running values in the [resulting queries](https://dbfiddle.uk/nAtXxv-J).